# Storing objects in the array

Tags: c++, boost, signals, boost-any

I want to save boost signals objects in the map (association: signal name → signal object). The signals signature is different, so the second type of map should be **boost::any**.

```
map<string, any> mSignalAssociation;
```

The question is how to store objects without defining type of new signal signature?

```
typedef boost::signals2::signal<void (int KeyCode)> sigKeyPressed;
mSignalAssociation.insert(make_pair("KeyPressed", sigKeyPressed()));
// This is what I need: passing object without type definition
mSignalAssociation["KeyPressed"] = (typename boost::signals2::signal<void (int KeyCode)>());
// One more trying which won't work. And I don't want use this
sigKeyPressed mKeyPressed;
mSignalAssociation["KeyPressed"] = mKeyPressed;
```

All this tryings throw the error:

```
/usr/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp: In copy constructor ‘boost::signals2::signal_base::signal_base(const boost::signals2::signal_base&)’: 
In file included from /usr/include/boost/signals2/detail/signals_common.hpp:17:0, 
/usr/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp:27:7: error: ‘boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable(const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable&)’ is private 
/usr/include/boost/signals2/signal_base.hpp:22:5: error: within this context 
---------- 
/usr/include/boost/signals2/detail/signal_template.hpp: In copy constructor ‘boost::signals2::signal1<void, int&, boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void(int)>, boost::function<void(const boost::signals2::connection&, int)>, boost::signals2::mutex>::signal1(const boost::signals2::signal1<void, int, boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void(int)>, boost::function<void(const boost::signals2::connection&, int)>, boost::signals2::mutex>&)’: 
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52:0, 
/usr/include/boost/signals2/detail/signal_template.hpp:578:5: note: synthesized method ‘boost::signals2::signal_base::signal_base(const boost::signals2::signal_base&)’ first required here 
                from /usr/include/boost/signals2.hpp:16, 
--------- 
/usr/include/boost/signals2/preprocessed_signal.hpp: In copy constructor ‘boost::signals2::signal<void(int)>::signal(const boost::signals2::signal<void(int)>&)’: 
In file included from /usr/include/boost/signals2/signal.hpp:36:0, 
/usr/include/boost/signals2/preprocessed_signal.hpp:42:5: note: synthesized method ‘boost::signals2::signal1<void, int, boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void(int)>, boost::function<void(const boost::signals2::connection&, int)>, boost::signals2::mutex>::signal1(const boost::signals2::signal1<void, int, boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void(int)>, boost::function<void(const boost::signals2::connection&, int)>, boost::signals2::mutex>&)’ first required here 
                from /home/ockonal/Workspace/Projects/Pseudoform-2/include/Core/Systems.hpp:6,
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by: "The question is how to store objects without defining type of new signal signature?"

Comment: @gman, I don't want to define new type of signal signature. And just use it directly during inserting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `any` or `map`. Boost signals are simply non-copyable. You can wrap them in a smart pointer such as `shared_ptr` if you want something that's copyable and cleans up after itself.

Comment: How to make wrapping without type definition? I tried:
`shared_ptr<typename signals2::signal<void (int KeyCode)> keyEvent;`

But it says about wrong first param in template.

Comment: You don't need a `typename` there. It is only needed for types which are dependent on template type parameters, but yours case isn't that, and `typename` is prohibited there.